# Can Oracle stored functions be called from Entity Framework nowadays?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-5

is this information from year 2011:

"Only Oracle stored procedures can be called by Entity Framework, not stored functions"
and
literal date type representation causes an error

still topical when using new Oracle database .NET provider (dated August, 2013) and EF5?